# jQuery - Call ajax every 10 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a mysql feedback database constructed like this:

> name | location | feedback
>
> Ryan  |  England |    great support

Obviously there's more entries than that. I am trying to build a feedback div, where it displays a new feedback item every 10 seconds via ajax.

So I have constructed this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   new get_fb(); 
 });

function get_fb(){
var feedback = $.ajax({//Ajax
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "feedback.php",
                        async: false
                        }).responseText;//end of ajax

$('div.feedback-box').html(feedback).delay(10000).queue(function() {
    new get_fb(); 
    });
}
```

And here's my PHP file:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feedback ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $location = $row['location'];
    $feedback = $row['feedback'];

    echo "
    <p>Name: $name, Location: $location, Feedback: $feedback.</p>
    ";
}
```

However, this only shows two. It doesn't keep showing new ones, it purely shows the first then the second and stops.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Are you going to want to do a `setInterval()`?

```
setInterval(function(){get_fb();}, 10000);
```

Or:

```
setInterval(get_fb, 10000);
```

Or, if you want it to run only after successfully completing the call, you can set it up in your `.ajax().success()` callback:

```
function get_fb(){
    var feedback = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feedback.php",
        async: false
    }).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_fb();}, 10000);
    }).responseText;

    $('div.feedback-box').html(feedback);
}
```

Or use `.ajax().complete()` if you want it to run regardless of result:

```
function get_fb(){
    var feedback = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feedback.php",
        async: false
    }).complete(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_fb();}, 10000);
    }).responseText;

    $('div.feedback-box').html(feedback);
}
```

Here is a demonstration of the two. Note, the success works only once because jsfiddle is returning a 404 error on the ajax call.

http://jsfiddle.net/YXMPn/

Comment: I noticed I had eliminated the `.responseText` portion of the code, which would have broken the functionality. See my last edit.

Comment: Just coming back to this project of mine. Is this suitable for use? I mean will it cause strain on the server? The website is only a electrical company not a large scale really. :/

Comment: If it's every ten seconds, only after the last one completes for a user, and you have a relatively small user base (<500 concurrent), I imagine you'll be fine. You just have to make sure your PHP script is optimized.

Comment: Take into account if you put it in your success callback, it will duplicate every time. That's not the correct way it should be done if it's a function.

Comment: Once I used setInterval for ajax with 5 seconds interval and let the page opened for continuous 6 hours and the whole browser hanged, CPU usage was 23+% all the time (almost one core at 100% since it was on dual core hyperthreaded CPU). It looks like setInterval causes kind of cpu/memory leak and very unreliable for your clients if they keep watching your webpage for a long time.

Answer (score 19):

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"myurl.html",
      datatype:"html",
      success:function(data)
      {
          //do something with response data
      }
    });
}, 10000);//time in milliseconds
```

Comment: @Muhammed - You have a misaligned double quote on the url property.

Comment: is it good to add this code when page have lots of jquery functions and data on a current page

Comment: It's better to use setTimeout. SetInterval will hit the the server regardless whether the previous call was stil running or not.

Answer (score 4):

You could try setInterval() instead:

```
var i = setInterval(function(){
   //Call ajax here
},10000)
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
setInterval(ajax_query, 10000);

function ajax_query(){
   //Call ajax here
}
```