# jQuery ajax call set timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "data.php"
}).done(function(data) { 
    //code
});
```

how to wrap this in jQuery timeout function for example send an ajax request every 2 sec.?

Comment: there is no jQuery timeout... you have javascript `setTimeout` like `setInterval(function(){...}, 2000)`

Comment: do you want to set a timeout or an interval?

Comment: Use `setInterval()` - although I'd question why you need to do this every 2 seconds? If you need that level of concurrency use websockets.

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687600/jquery-call-ajax-every-10-seconds

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You probably need to include some check to see if the previous call has completed before making a new one.

Comment: how can i do this @Johan ?

Comment: Save the ajax call in a variable and look if `.readyState < 4`. If it's true, it hasn't been completed.

Comment: can i use jQuery "complete" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrap this in a `setInterval`, you run the risk of sending your server a ton of requests with the potential of not getting them all back in order. Put a `timeout` inside the callback:

```
function runAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php"
    }).done(function(data) { 
        //code
        setTimeout(runAjax, 2000); //Run it again in 2 sec
    });
}

runAjax(); //I suppose we should start the AJAX :D
```

Comment: maybe add runAjax() beneath to actually call the function once to get it starting :)

Comment: @Alex -- Probably a good idea :)

Comment: i  want to refresh a particualr div when there is new content how can i do it

Comment: @rexhin -- Load the content into the new div in the `.done`

Comment: yes i know but how to refresh it when there is new content in data.php

Comment: @rexhin -- You have to replace the HTML of the targeted div with the response from `data.php`

Comment: You should use long polling instead: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
var ajax = null;
function callAjax()
{
  if(ajax != null)
     ajax.abort();
  ajax = $.ajax({
    url: "data.php"
  }).done(function(data) { 
    //code
  });
  setTimeout(callAjax, 1000); // Every 1 second
}
callAjax();
```

This code will execute the Ajax call once every 1 second. If another request is running, it will kill it before running another one.

A better way would be to use long polling:
http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: id rather but the timeout call in the done callback

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to ensure the requests are sent every second or if you want to launch it again one second after it succeeds. It's actually much different.

Comment: Why not `if(ajax && ajax.readyState < 4)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

```
var xhr;
setInterval(
   function runAjax() {
        if(xhr) {
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: "data.php"
        }).done(function(data) { 

        });
    }, 2000
)
```

try like this.

Comment: This is actually pretty bad: if the server starts to be slow, many requests will get queued.

Comment: we can cancel the requests those are queued by using abort method of xhr.

Comment: Yes, but it was not in the first version of your script, was it ?