# PHP+AJAX refresh div not correctly working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to refresh SQL data that is displayed onto my page. I want it to refresh every second. At the moment, after the balance has been displayed, after the 1 second the data stays but it doesn't update.

JS Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                var htmlstring= "<?php echo "Balance: $".$_SESSION['Money']." || "; ?>";
                $('#money').text(htmlstring);
            }, 1000);
        });
</script>
```

HTML+PHP code:

```
<span id="money"><?php echo "Balance: $".$_SESSION['Money']." || ";?></span>
```

This is where the session is being set:

```
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "website");
if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
$result = $con->query("select * from users where   UserID=".$_SESSION['UserID']);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['Money'] = $row['Money'];
```

Could it be because the session that is set isn't being refreshed? If so, how would I change that?

Comment: The session variable is not being refreshed. Where is the code for setting the session variable?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Updated question with code.

Comment: Every time you do the interval call you have to run the query which sets the session variable.

Comment: @jayBlanchard so where do I put the PHP code with the query? I'm new to using ajax...

Comment: Ask your SESSION data by AJAX, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687600/jquery-call-ajax-every-10-seconds

Comment: You're not using AJAX here. Under normal conditions it would be [page with AJAX makes a request to PHP code which returns values to AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: Take a look at the chosen answer in the link above.

Comment: That's what @JayBlanchard said. BTW, is it better for community pointing this question as duplicate, as question 5687600 helps to solve it?

Comment: But I've tried implementing what is said there into my code and it doesnt work.